# Distance of a chord from the circles center

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a circle defined:
$$
(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=100
$$

The question is, if the length of a chord is 16, what's the distance between the line it lies on and the center of the circle?

---

Since there is infinitely many tendons of length 16, I can pick any one. I decided to use one where k in y=kx + l is 0, so the line it lies on is defined with y=l, a horozontal line.

Here's where I've decided to complicate things. If I were to draw a circle around the chord, the task could be redefined as finding the distance between the two  circles centers.

This is the circle:
$$
(x-2)^2+(y-q)^2=64
$$

I also know that the coordinates of the chord intersections are x,y and x+16,y.

Going from here I always end up with a 4th power polynomial and don't really know what to do.

There must be a simpler way, it is high school math.

Comment: The word *tendon* isn't standard; presumably you mean *chord* (i.e., the line segment joining two points of a circle)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I know my general english, but math lingo... Not so much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instinct to choose a horizontal chord is good. Here's a hint:

[image]

Comment: Seriously? Oh come on...

Comment: @Karlovsky120 This way is simpler than solving a quartic polynomial. ;)

Comment: You can scale it by $1/2$, see it, and rescale by $2$.

Comment: And to think I used to believe I'm clever.